# Angular Memory leaking and subscription not working properly

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, observable, subscription

I'm giving a try to Ionic and I wanted to do a currency converter to practice. The app retrieves some data from an API Rest, then in the front end is used to calculate the exchange rate of a certain amount of money. I want it to work just like preev.com works.

I have a service that gets the data from an API Rest and it takes two parameters, which are the currencies to convert among. Then the service make a get request to the right endpoint depending on the parameters/currencies.

In my Page, I have a function that sends the parameters/currencies to the service and then it subscribe to it.

In this part I'm experiencing two problems:

1. The first one is because is an observable, it gets updated too often. I tried to solve this by making interval request to the server every 60 seconds but it didn't work, and the other way I tried to solve it was by trying to retrieve the value once from component before the subscription by using `first()` method.
2. When I switch between currencies in my select component, the `targetAmount` flashes between the current exchange value and the past exchange value. For example, the default currencies to exchange in my app are BTC/CLP, but when I select BTC/COP, it flashes the two exchanges rates for a few seconds until it shows the current exchange rate which is what I intend to. Last, when I switch among currencies without waiting to show just the current exchange, it crashes.

Here is my code:

Page:

```
export class Page {

  baseCurrency = 'BTC';
  targetCurrency = 'CLP';
  baseAmount = 1;
  exchangeRate: number;
  subscription;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    private exchangeService: ExchangeService) {

  }

  supportedCurrencies = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'BCH'];
  supportedCurrencies2 = ['CLP', 'COP', 'PEN'];

  get targetAmount() {
    this.subscription = this.exchangeService.getBudaFiat(this.baseCurrency, this.targetCurrency)
    .first()
    .subscribe(
      val => {
        this.exchangeRate = val.ticker.last_price[0];
      }
    )
    return this.baseAmount * this.exchangeRate;
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    console.log("SALIO");
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="baseAmount"
      [class.error]="isInvalid(baseAmount)">
    <currency-select [(selected)]="baseCurrency"></currency-select>
    = <strong>{{targetAmount}}</strong>
    <currency-select2 [(selected)]="targetCurrency"></currency-select2>
    <p *ngIf="isInvalid(baseAmount)">Please enter a valid amount</p>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Service:

```
getBudaFiat(baseCurrency: string, targetCurrency: string) {
    return Observable.interval(60000)
    .startWith(0)
    .switchMap(() => {
      return this.http.get(`https://wt-e2369b36b992e69ccc8f05d9b48dd8e2-0.sandbox.auth0-extend.com/cryptoalarma/${baseCurrency}${targetCurrency}`)
      .map((response: Response) => response);
    });
  }
```

The code is also avalaible on Stackblitz and you can check the problem in the Contact tab:

[Stackblitz app link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yljfbt)

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I forgot to mention that in the second problem I explained, it starts to use a lot of memory until the app freezes.

Comment: Where is that memory leak pointed in the title??

Comment: @Antoniossss sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Subscription properly:

```
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';
```

and then type your subscription variable:

```
subscription: Subscription;
```

and finally

```
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: That last part is the most important.

Comment: If you try to unsubscribe a subscription that is not typed to Subscription, it will not unsubscribe. It should give you a linting error as well.

Comment: Hey Sandra, thanks for your help, but it's not working. It does unsubscribe when I leave the page but I still have the main problems. If I switch between currencies it starts to use a lot memory and flashes the exchange rates.
You can check this here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yljfbt?file=pages%2Fabout%2Fabout.ts

Your solution is implemented under the About tab

Comment: This typically happens because you have unsubscribed, but you Subject is still emitting...

Answer (score 0):

I am using this way which is very neat and you don't need to create variables for each subscription

1. create a variable called `alive` with default `true`
2. Use `.takeWhile(() => this.alive)` before `subscribe`
3. implement `OnDestroy`
4. set `alive` to false on `ngOnDestroy`

then **automagically** it will unsubscribe observable when your component is destroyed

```
export class MyComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  public user: User;
  private alive: boolean = true;

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.authenticate(email, password)
      .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.user = user;
      });

    this.otherService.getdata()
      .takeWhile(() => this.alive)
      .subscribe(data => {
      });

  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.alive = false;
  }

}
```

You can read more in [here](http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/)

Comment: Hey RezaRahmati, thanks for your help, but it's not working. It still uses a lot of memory and it flashes the currency exchange rates also. You can check this here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yljfbt?file=pages%2Fcontact%2Fcontact.ts Your solution is implemented under the Contact tab

Comment: @ClaudioRamírezGuichard you didn't implement `OnDestroy` and `ngOnDestroy` to set `alive` to `false`

Comment: I did it, it's just that after it didn't work I tried with `ionViewWillLeave()`. Anyway, in the link you gave me it still flashes among exchange rates when you switch the currencies to convert to. BTW, I just realized that the http fails also and starts to show a lot of errors in the console. When that happens memory leaks increases.

Comment: @ClaudioRamírezGuichard The issue with your code is that you are subscribing in `get targetAmount` which means every time the get property is called you subscribe again, instead it's better to have event handler for currency change, call your api using first() or take(1) and store total amount in a variable.